# How to retrieve all the Groups/Roles a user is member of using SOAP services?

Tags: soap, liferay, remote-access

I am trying to collect some user informations using SOAP services.

I was able to get the Job Title for a given user, but I don't understand how to retrieve the list of groups and roles that a user has.

Can I simply use the `GroupServiceSoap.getUserPlaces(long userId, String[] classNames, int max)` method?  Or is there another way I can get these fields?

Currently my code:

```
private static URL _getURL(String remoteUser, String password, String serviceName) {
    final String LIFERAY_PROTOCOL = "http://";
    final String LIFERAY_TCP_PORT = "8080";
    final String LIFERAY_FQDN = "localhost";
    final String LIFERAY_AXIS_PATH = "/api/secure/axis/";
    try {
        return new URL(LIFERAY_PROTOCOL + URLEncoder.encode(remoteUser, "UTF-8") + ":"
                        + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "@" + LIFERAY_FQDN
                        + ":" + LIFERAY_TCP_PORT + LIFERAY_AXIS_PATH + serviceName);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return null;
    } 
}

[...]
public static void main(String[] argv){

    public final String LIFERAY_USER_SERVICE="Portal_UserService";
    public final String LIFERAY_COMPANY_SERVICE="Portal_CompanyService";
    public final String LIFERAY_GROUP_SERVICE = "Portal_GroupService";

    //company.default.web.id property
    public final String LIFERAY_DEFAULT_COMPANY_ID = "liferay.com";

    UserServiceSoap userService = new UserServiceSoapServiceLocator().getPortal_UserService(_getURL(USER_IDENTIFIER,USER_PASSWORD, LIFERAY_USER_SERVICE));

    //This code is usefull if you want to use SOAP setter.
    //((Portal_UserServiceSoapBindingStub) userService).setUsername(USER_IDENTIFIER);
    //((Portal_UserServiceSoapBindingStub) userService).setPassword(USER_PASSWORD);

    CompanyServiceSoap companyService = new CompanyServiceSoapServiceLocator().getPortal_CompanyService(_getURL(USER_IDENTIFIER, USER_PASSWORD, LIFERAY_COMPANY_SERVICE));
    long companyId = companyService.getCompanyByMx(LIFERAY_DEFAULT_COMPANY_ID).getCompanyId();

    // Here I retrieve my user, and can access some properties, but not them all ! 
    UserSoap user = userService.getUserByEmailAddress(companyId, target_user_mail);

    //TODO : I got hte JobTittle that I want, later I will do something more util thant just print it, I swear it my precious !
    System.out.println(user.getJobTitle());

    GroupServiceSoap groupService = new GroupServiceSoapServiceLocator().getPortal_GroupService(_getURL(USER_IDENTIFIER, USER_PASSWORD, LIFERAY_GROUP_SERVICE));

    //this one return an empty array
    GroupSoap[] userPlaces = groupService.getUserPlaces(new String[]{"Group", "Role"}, 150);

    //this return an array of size 1, but the only GroupSoap seems to be a structural groups without any usefull properties to me.
    GroupSoap[] userPlaces = groupService.getUserPlaces(null, 150);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only a partial answer.

In order to get all the User Roles one can do this :

```
RoleServiceSoap roleService =  new RoleServiceSoapServiceLocator().getPortal_RoleService(_getURL(USER_IDENTIFIER, USER_PASSWORD, LIFERAY_ROLE_SERVICE));
RoleSoap[] userRoles = roleService.getUserRoles(user.getUserId());
```

with user variable an instance of UserSoap.

The SOAP access must be done by an Admin user in order to get access to the Role List. The user can't access this himself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get user role and group user id

```
UserServiceSoap.getRoleUserIds
UserServiceSoap.getGroupUserIds
```

HTH

Comment: these methods do the inverse of what I need !
Seeing the API it is write : 
public static long[] getGroupUserIds(long groupId)
                              throws RemoteException

    Returns the primary keys of all the users belonging to the group. 

I want the exact opposite. I need to retrieve the groups Ids from a user Id.

Comment: can elaborate what exactly you need?

Comment: I have one user Id and I need to get the list of groups and role that the user is in.